# Right syntax near MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
select c.*
from costs c
where 32 between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and 34 between c.y + c.deltay
order by priority desc
limit 1
```

Keeps saying `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by priority desc limit 1' at line 4`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `between` only has one condition to check, it is missing the `and`:

```
34 between c.y + c.deltay
```

Do you want to use?

```
34 between c.y and c.y + c.deltay
```

Comment: I also get `#1054 - Unknown column 'x.num' in 'field list'` when running `select x.num as x, y.num as y
from numbers x cross join
     numbers y`

Comment: @user2279927 Do you have a column called `num`?